# SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, ddl

I'm new to mysql. I'm making a stored proc. I need to create a temp table under that. However, while doing so I'm getting below error:
**SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near ')
BEGIN
DECLARE a bigint Default 0 ;
DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
' at line 1**
I'm unable to get what's wrong anyways with  my sql statement. Attaching script for the same. Any help to fix this error will be really appreciated. My mysql version is 5.7

```
    DELIMITER $$  

    CREATE PROCEDURE ABC(in fullstr varchar)

      BEGIN
    DECLARE a bigint  ;
    DECLARE str VARCHAR;
    DECLARE v_statment varchar;
    set @v_statment = ('create temporary table count_temp (id 
    bigint auto_increment , 
    subscriberid bigint , PRIMARY KEY (id))') ;
    prepare stmt from @v_statment ;
    execute stmt;
    simple_loop: LOOP
    SET a=a+1;
    SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);
    IF str='' THEN
    LEAVE simple_loop;
    END IF;
   
    insert into count_temp (subscriberid) values (str);
    END LOOP simple_loop;

    END $$
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: Make sure you have no white space after `DELIMITER $$` and make sure you have a proper newline after it. The formatting of your question makes me think you have extra space that is confusing the parser.

Comment: @BillKarwin - there was I problem with formatting - I cleared it now. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: The first error is that `VARCHAR` needs a length, like `VARCHAR(50)`.  I also see a use of the function `SPLIT_STR()` which is not supported by MySQL. I think you're using Microsoft SQL Server features on MySQL. These are two different software products, with different features and syntax. You need to study the documentation for MySQL if you use MySQL.